# How can I use Google Translate for translating values in a website form field (text box, text area)?

Tags: language-translation, google-translator-toolkit

I want to translate my website using [Google Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate). I used the code below.

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en'
    }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

It is working fine with text of the website, but does not translate the text box, text area's text. Is there a solution?

Comment: The prepared should be you result nary amicable for the most part. Translation automatic is can be helpful for thus called gist translation albeit not fully reimbursed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through the elements in your page and make individual ajax calls to Google Translate API to translate them one by one and them replace the textbox/textarea values.

Using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), you can iterate through your textbox, textareas and everything else you want to. The code should be something like:

```
$('input:text').each(function(index) {

    var elementId = $(this).attr("id"); 

    //Call the Google API
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data : "v=1.0&q="+$("#"+elementId).val()+"&langpair=en|es",
        success : function(iData){
            //update the value
            $("#"+elementId).val(iData["responseData"]["translatedText"]);      
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ }
    });
});
```

As you can see, the parameter `&langpair=en|es` asks to translate from English to Spanish.

Just remember that one call will be made for each `<input type="text".../>`, so you might want to add some kind of validation to filter useless calls! You might also want to validate Google's answer.

Here is a link in order to understand the kind of response Google will send you:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_translate.html

**EDIT:** Since free use of Google's API will be shut down on 2011-12-01, you could use Apertium. The call and response is almost the same: `http://api.apertium.org/json/translate?q=hello%20world&langpair=en|es`

Comment: Also note that Google will be shutting down the API in a few months, apparently because of efforts like this one. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2590374

Comment: I agree with @tripleee If your page contains a lot of input boxes and text areas, this method is not the best, since you will be throwing a lot of calls to the API, and if your site has a lot of traffic, Google won't love you.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that Apertium's language repertoire is fairly limited, at least for the time being.

Comment: The apertium API url should be: `https://www.apertium.org/apy/translate?q=hello%20world&langpair=en|es`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, is to wrap all calls in @pgratton's answer in only one call. Separate everything by using tags.

For example, put all contents of three textboxes in one string like this:

```
<t1>Desk</t1><t2>Monitor</t2><t3>Keyboard</t3>
```

And send it to the Google API. You will then get something like:

```
<t1>Secretária</t1><t2>Ecrã</t2><t3>Teclado</t3>
```

This is how you can save API calls. I've tried it almost two years ago and it was working then. You just need to make sure that the tags or whatever you're using to separate the fields are not translated and don't get lost in translation. The separators must be kept.